# Could there be a class of drugs beyond, similar to barbiturates and benzodiazepines?

Tags: organic-chemistry, pharmacology

I'm talking about group of drugs similar to them but different though.Is there anything beyond benzodiazepines?

Comment: Similar in structure or effect - and if so, which effect?

Comment: I'm talking generally sedatives/anxiolytics. If you have any knowledge about potentials in structre i'd also appreciate it.

Comment: The Serotonin/Noradrenaline reuptake inhibitors have activity against anxiety/depression

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia has a list of [sedatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sedative) divided into 13 categories: barbiturates, benzodiazepines, orexin antagonists, herbal sedatives, general anesthetics, antidepressants, antihistamines, opioids, etc.

A list of [anxiolytics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anxiolytic) greatly overlaps with sedatives, but additionally includes sympatholytics, carbamates and some other individual drugs.

Comment: I'm talking more about undiscovered could there be something beyond benzos

Comment: There could be, this remains an area of interest to many pharma companies. Small molecules that act at glutamate receptors for example: https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2013/10/131006142321.htm